# Simple charge pump - what’s advantage?

Tags: capacitor, boost, charge-pump

Consider simple charge pump. If the output voltage is close to 11V there is no swing across Cfly. To get some swing on Cfly the output voltage has to be 8V or so.
But 2V boost is for nothing.
So what I am thinking wrong?
Where is the application area it can be used?

[image]

Comment: What's the point of L here? Why do you say that a 2 V boost isn't useful?

Comment: @Hearth L limits the current taken from source. Also, L avoids Cfly capacitor from huge current spikes. For 2V boost I can add one battery more to power source.

Comment: And is that one more battery a more efficient use of money and device size than this charge pump (or a better-designed, more efficient charge pump that can boost to even higher voltages), especially considering how everything else will need to be adjusted to the different battery voltage? Probably not.